# SCPクライアントを用いた踏み台サーバー経由でのアクセスについて

Tags: macos, aws, ssh

mac -> aws環境で踏み台サーバー経由でSCPクライアントを用いてサーバーBにアクセスをしたいと考えております。

SCPクライアントは現在cyberduckを想定しております。

踏み台サーバー　user_a
サーバーB　user_b
がおり、それぞれにssh秘密キーがあります。

同一ユーザー、同一秘密キーの場合はトンネルで接続できるのはわかっているのですが
上記のような、踏み台サーバー、サーバーBでそれぞれユーザーが違い、かつsshのキーも異なる場合は
どのような設定をすればよいのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cyberduckはわからないのですが、SSHポートフォワーディングで解決できないでしょうか。
最初に ssh コマンドに `-L` を指定して踏み台に接続します。

Ex) localhost の 10999ポートを server-b の 22 (SSH) ポートに転送

```
ssh -L 10999:server-b:22 -i keyfile user@servername
```

次にSCPクライアントから つぎのように接続してください。

サーバー: localhost
ポート： 10999
ユーザ名： user_b
秘密鍵： user_bの秘密鍵

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました！！